# Playframework Images.resize() without auto rotating the picture

Tags: java, playframework, blob, playframework-1.x

I'm using Play Framework 1.2.4. and `Blob Images.resize(File originalImage, File to, int w, int h)` to resize a picture.

When the picture is Portrait (height is greater than width) the output is automatically rotated, how can I prevent this behavior?

**Here are the examples:**

Original Image:

[image: Original Image before resize]

Resized Image is rotated:

[image]

I appreciate any advice or comments.

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  Perhaps there is Exif data on the image (saying to display it rotated).  This happens often with phone pictures.  Does the same thing happen with landscape pictures?

I use this library: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/ and it is not immune to the Exif rotation issue either.  There are other SO posts about how to handle that: [How to rotate JPEG images based on the orientation metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905868/am-i-making-this-too-complicated-image-rotation)

Comment: landscape pictures are good, it seems like Blob prefers a landscape and rotates portrait to make it landscape, and thanks for the imgscalr like.

Comment: you might try testing your theory by making a portrait sized picture with a paint program.  i suspect it is exif data, rather than the dimensions.