# Image Upload then automatically image are rotate in Preview Image tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading the image in file upload control on change event then image is automatically rotate see in preview tag in my asp.net mvc c# but I am upload the existing image upload it's good but I am click the image in iPhone then image are upload that time image is rotate. This below code is used for the preview image.

This is my file upload control

```xml
 <img id="PreviewImage" class="mb20" width="300" src="../@Url.Content(@Url.Content(Model.ProfileImage))" />                                        
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserFileUpload, new { type = "file", onchange = "ShowVehicleImagePreview(this)" })
```

this is my function

```
function ShowVehicleImagePreview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var readervehicle = new FileReader();
        readervehicle.onload = function (e) {
            $('#PreviewImage').prop('src', e.target.result).width(300);
        };
        readervehicle.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Any one have the idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the image file it self has `orientation` metadata and the iPhone show it to you as correctly rotated because it's correcting the image, maybe this answer can help:
[How to rotate JPEG images based on the orientation metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905868/how-to-rotate-jpeg-images-based-on-the-orientation-metadata)