# Java:getHeight() on BufferedImage is returning image width and getWidth() is returning image height

Tags: java, image, metadata

I am compressing an image doing Jpeg compression in Java and then resizing them before storing. I am keeping the storage height as `480` and calculating the `height` based on aspect ratio, so to keep the original `height:width` ratio same.

This is the code I am using

```
String inputImagePath = "1.JPG";
String outputImagePath = "Test Compression\\" + "1.JPG";

File imageFile = new File(inputImagePath);
File compressedImageFile = new File(outputImagePath);

int height = 640;

System.out.print("Conversion Start!\n");

if (imageFile != null)
{

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

    float quality = 0.2 f;

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);

    double aspectRatio = (double) image.getWidth() / image.getHeight();

    width = (int)(height * aspectRatio);
    System.out.println("Original height = " + image.getHeight() + " Original  width = " + image.getWidth());
    System.out.println(" aspect ratio = " + aspectRatio);
    System.out.println("height = " + height + " width = " + width + " aspect ratio = " + aspectRatio);

    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

    if (!writers.hasNext())
        throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");

    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(resizedImage, null, null), param);
}

System.out.print("Conversion compete!");
```

Here is the image metadata

[image: Here width = 1920, height = 2560]

Here is the printed content:

```
Original height = 1920 Original  width = 2560
aspect ratio = 1.3333333333333333

height = 480 width = 640
aspect ratio = 1.3333333333333333
```

I applied the code to other images which actually had `width > height` and I had no rotation issues. This rotaion issue is only occuring for the images with `height > width` As far as I know there is nothing wrong in my code, I must be missing something related to getHeight() and getWidth() functions. Please help me out

Comment: Could you update your code sample with your height variable as well? It seems to be missing.

Comment: I update the code with `height` variable. I got desired results using      [metadata extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor)  as suggested by Sergey Grinev by the way. I posted it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be rotation metadata in the jpeg images which Java doesn't recognize by default.

It looks like: `Orientation  : rotate 90` in the jpeg properties.

You need a 3rd party library to handle it, see [How to rotate JPEG images based on the orientation metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905868/how-to-rotate-jpeg-images-based-on-the-orientation-metadata)

Answer (score 1):

For future references, I got through the references given by Sergey Grinev and altered the code a little bit and got desired results. Here is the code

```html
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imageFile);
Directory directory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
   
int orientation = 1;
try{
orientation = directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);
} catch (MetadataException me) {
System.out.println("Could not get orientation");
}

int orgWidth = image.getWidth();
int orgHeight = image.getHeight();
   
double orgAspectRatio = (double)orgWidth/orgHeight;
   
   
AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp;
BufferedImage orientedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), image.getType());
  
boolean rotation = false;
         
switch (orientation) {
  case 1:
        orientedImage = image;
        break;
  case 2: // Flip X
        affineTransform.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
        affineTransform.translate(-orgWidth, 0);
     affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);  
     orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
     break;
   case 3: // PI rotation
          affineTransform.translate(orgWidth, orgHeight);
          affineTransform.rotate(Math.PI);
          affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform,AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
         orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
         break;
   case 4: // Flip Y
          affineTransform.scale(1.0, -1.0);
          affineTransform.translate(0, -orgHeight);
  affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
          orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
          break;
   case 5: // - PI/2 and Flip X
         rotation = true;
            affineTransform.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
            affineTransform.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
   affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
            orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
            break;
   case 6: // -PI/2 and -width
         rotation = true;
            affineTransform.translate(orgHeight, 0);
            affineTransform.rotate(Math.PI/2);
   affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
            orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
            break;
   case 7: // PI/2 and Flip
         rotation = true;
            affineTransform.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
            affineTransform.translate(-orgHeight, 0);
            affineTransform.translate(0, orgWidth);
            affineTransform.rotate(3 * Math.PI / 2);
   affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
            orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
            break;
   case 8: // PI / 2
         rotation = true;
            affineTransform.translate(0, orgWidth);
            affineTransform.rotate(3 * Math.PI / 2);
   affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
            orientedImage = affineTransformOp.filter(image, orientedImage);
            break;
   default:
         orientedImage = image;
            break;
        }       
         
double aspectRatio;
         
if(rotation){
     aspectRatio = (double)orientedImage.getWidth()/orientedImage.getHeight();
       width = outWidth;
        height = (int)(width/aspectRatio);
        }
        else{
         aspectRatio = (double)orientedImage.getWidth()/orientedImage.getHeight();
          width = (int)(height*aspectRatio);
        }
```